# Fetching a specific word from a string

Tags: php

I'm in love with `strstr` but this time it's not that helpful for me... Why?

I want to be able to fetch the seventh word from a string.

for example :

```
$myString = 'Dummy string just to fetch the seventh word.';
echo strstr($myString, ' ', true);
```

Obviously, This return :

```
Dummy{+space}
```

I was wondering if there is an internal php command right of the box that would let me fetch the 7 word of every string (instead of writing a function).

Obviously, For this example I'm expecting to get a trimmed :

```
seventh
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode` to split the string into an array with a specific delimiter and then acces the right element in this array.

Example:

```
$array = explode(" ", $myString);
echo $array[6];
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing ;-) Just curious if there is internal php command right of the box...

Comment: I don't think so. But I think the `explode` way is the easiest.

Comment: All the PHP string functions can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php if it's not there it doesn't exist..

Comment: I think it should be achievable with a regular expression, but I think that it would be worse looking and slower than the explode way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myStringArray = explode('', $myString);
print_r($myStringArray);
```

result:

```
[0]=>'Dummy'
[1]=>'string'
[2]=>'just'
[3]=>'to'
[4]=>'fetch'
[5]=>'the'
[6]=>'seventh'
[7]=>'word.'
```